# Feature Navigation for PopupTemplate attached to overlapping Graphic

Tags: arcgis, arcgis-js-api

I have a MapView with two point graphics with identical lat/long:

```
var view = new MapView(...)

view.graphics.add(new Graphic({
  geometry: {
    type: "point",
    longitude: "-90",
    latitude: "40"
  },
  symbol: {  type: "simple-marker", ... },
  popupTemplate: { title: "some title" }
});

view.graphics.add(new Graphic({
  geometry: {
    type: "point",
    longitude: "-90",
    latitude: "40"
  },
  symbol: {  type: "simple-marker", ... },
  popupTemplate: { title: "some title" }
});
```

What I want is to be able to toggle between popups of the two graphics with navigation controls. I had previously been able to do this in API version up to 4.9, but since upgrading to 4.10+ this behavior is no longer there. Below are pictures of the issue:

(version 4.6 https://i.stack.imgur.com/ve5AZ.png )

(version 4.12 https://i.stack.imgur.com/vQ4Gg.png )

Simply changing API versions resulted in these differences in navigation controls being displayed.

Comment: To show more than one, you need to have more than one record in the "PopUp.features" variable. Do you have this?

Comment: To clarify, I'm not using the Popup API at all. Instead, I have multiple `Graphic`s at the exact same lat/long with `popupTemplate`s. In previous versions, feature navigation would show. In the current version, they do not.

Comment: Can you provide some more details? What kind of geometries are you using and how do you visualize them? A running example would be very helpful!

Comment: @ArnoFiva I've gone ahead and rephrased the question and added a code snippet! Any help would be much appreciated